# How to configure eclipse to write Perl code

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl programming. Could someone please point me to a link or answer me so as to how should I write Perl code in eclipse?

like, do I need a plugin or something, if yes how?

Comment: Your question is valid question, but unfortunately, such question are considered too broad in stackoverflow. Over that stackexchange is not having any forum to address such questions. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on following links. Hopefully this will give you some basic idea.

[Running Perl Scripts Within Eclipse](http://www.epic-ide.org/running_perl_scripts_within_eclipse/entry.htm)

[Running Perl with Eclipse](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEgQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdigital.cs.usu.edu%2F~allanv%2Fcs4700%2FEclipsePerl.doc&ei=OccLVZyoAcrguQSXu4LIBA&usg=AFQjCNH3OJ5lj4z9VYvx6ZaWfvxtad-UwA&bvm=bv.88528373,d.c2E)

Answer (score 0):

EPIC - http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/index.php is a perl plugin for eclipse.

How to install: http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch01.php

note: this is and old plugin and I have not tested it with the latest versions of Eclipse. Last version I used was Indigo (3.7.2)